# Non-circular shift in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, bit-shift

Matlab has `circshift` which shifts matrix circularly, i.e. putting shifted out elements to opposite side.

Is there a function which shifts matrix with copying last values or padding new space with zeros? Like bitwise shift in C/C++ does?

**UPDATE**

I know I can write function myself.

Comment: [`bitshift()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html)?

Comment: No, I meant elements shift, not bits.

Comment: Please, provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. If there were, it would be under "Sorting and Reshaping Arrays" in the main Matlab function list.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/array-manipulation.html

So, as you say, you'll need to write your own. You could probably do a pretty concise implementation by writing the shift logic along dimension 1 and using `shiftdim` in a loop to rotate the matrix to effectively apply it to all the requested shift dimensions and then back to the original dimensional orientation.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use `circshift` and set the shifted space to zero manually. For example, if you had to shift a matrix left and have zeroes padded to the right, you'd do something like:

```
shifted_mat = circshift(mat, -1, 2);
shifted_mat(:, end) = 0;
```

The -1 and 2 in `circshift` denote the magnitude and the direction of shift respectively. You can use this for shifting up and down too.